# ASP.Net Page_Validators in iOS 8 Safari 8

Tags: asp.net, safari8

In my ASP.Net app with framwork 3.5, I am looping Page_Validators and apply css style to required fields but I does not work in ipad iOS 8 Safari 8

```
for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
    var val = Page_Validators[i];
    var ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
    if (ctrl != null && ctrl.style != null) {
        if (!CheckValidatorsForControl(ctrl))
            ctrl.className = "ValidationOn";
        else
            ctrl.className = "";
    }
}
```

Even if I try a basic javascript alert like below:
alert(Page_Validators.length);

Nothing happen in in ipad iOS 8 Safari 8. For all other browsers, everything is perfect.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When I view source, there is a lot of things missing e.g.
<form .... onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
and all the reqval javascript at the bottom of the page

Comment: Add the following code in the web.config file in the system.web section will fix the problem  <browserCaps>
   <filter>
    <case match="AppleWebKit/6\d\d">
     EcmaScriptVersion = 1.4
     w3cdomversion = 1.0
     supportsCallback = true
    </case>
    <case match="AppleWebKit/85\d">
     EcmaScriptVersion = 1.4
     w3cdomversion = 1.0
     supportsCallback = true
    </case>
   </filter>
  </browserCaps>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the fix provided by Marty Webb in his comment worked for me. Basically, .NET wasn't addding validation on my iOS browsers. This update to the Web.Config seems to fix it for me.

Update Web.config in the system.web section

```
    <browserCaps> 
       <filter> 
          <case match="AppleWebKit/6\d\d"> EcmaScriptVersion = 1.4 w3cdomversion = 1.0 supportsCallback = true </case> 
          <case match="AppleWebKit/85\d"> EcmaScriptVersion = 1.4 w3cdomversion = 1.0 supportsCallback = true </case>
       </filter> 
    </browserCaps>
```